# convert base64 string to image in php

Tags: php, base64

i want to convert image into byte array and save this byte array into my database after that i want to fetch this byte arrar and print on browser

for this i tried to passed an image in base64_encode() function which gives me string this string i passed into base64_decode() function.but image is not showing here is my code
this is my first file for storing image byte array

`

```
    $demo="/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAg";
    $data = base64_decode($demo);
    $host="localhost";
    $db="demo";
    $password="";
    $db_user="root";
    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$password) or die("connection not stablished");
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$db) or die("database not found");
    $temp=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO imagetable (image)
                VALUES ('".$data."')");
    if($temp==TRUE)
    {
      echo "image inserted";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "image not inserted";
    }
```

?>
`
this is my second file for display image

```
`<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","demo"); //keep your db name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagetable WHERE id=2";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

?>`

but it doesn't display image at browser instead it give error

> cannot be displayed because it contains error

Comment: Just `echo base64_decode($demo);`, no need for all the image conversion stuff.

Comment: i am trying also like `$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","demo"); //keep your db name
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM imagetable WHERE id=2";
 $sth = $db->query($sql);
 $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';`

Comment: there is a magical function called **edit** right below your question.

Comment: echo base64_decode($demo); giving me ÿØÿàJFIF``ÿÛC      ÿÛCÿÀ8á"ÿÄ ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”

Comment: If I paste your demo string into an base64-decoder (like http://www.base64decode.org/ or http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Decode/) the result is broken to start with. Is it really a working base64-string?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work (even if it doesn't really make sense).

Like @deceze already said you don't need to create it again with imagecreatefromstring(), you just need to echo the output.

Your problem seems to be that you don't encode the picture correctly.
A base64 of an image is usually a lot larger. I tested it with a 19x19px JPG and that had around 22000 characters.

Can you tell us how you encoded your picture and maybe provide your sample picture?
If you encoded it right, maybe it's not saved or retrieved correctly from the database?

In your example

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

it should be decode instead of encode.
Maybe that's already it.

Comment: base64_decode($demo);  not working. and string is not too short it's too long which i didn't mention full for sake of space. i convert image into string from this link  http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: Okay, after you updated I see what you did.

So basically you took a picture, used a Webservice to convert it to base64.
Then you put it in PHP to decode it and wrote the binary to the database.
Now you fetch it from the DB and encrypt it again and that doesn't work.

1. Does it work when you just output it (without going over the db)?
2. What field type to you use to save it in the DB?
3. Why don't you save the base64 encoded image directly instead of decryping and encrypting it again?

Answer (score 0):

`

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","demo"); //keep your db name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagetable WHERE id=1";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
//$data = explode(',', $result['image']);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$result['image'].'"/>';
```

?>`

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 should read base64_encode($demo);, not decode.